# Strange stripes with fglrx drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

I get strange stripes with the amd driver and with the driver from the repos (fglrx-updates, fglrx in both 14.04 and 15.10). I run Ubuntu 14.04 but had the same problem with 15.10. The screen also starts in the middle, goes out right and continues at the left. The stripes make everything unreadable. But! As soon as I plug in another Display (here TV) into the HDMI port, the screen is refreshed and the stripes and other problems are gone. But I can't plug in a TV anywhere (it's a laptop). Now, how can I solve this problem and let the screen refresh/reset itself without having to plug in another monitor/TV? Btw, the consoles Alt+F1 etc. have the same stripes and problems.

Comment: I have a 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M].